# Populate select field with time interval in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, field, advanced-custom-fields, auto-populate, acfpro

I have an option page with 2 fields.

**A number field for the time interval:**

booking_settings_openings_hours_interval

**And a repeater field with 2 subfields:**

booking_settings_opening_hours_start

booking_settings_opening_hours_end

The code below creates a list of all times (with interval X) from START to END time to populate a select field. The interval code works great but it doesn’t populate the select field with these time options.

**But when I replace:**

```
// explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
$choices = explode("\n", $choices);
```

**With this:**

```
// explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
echo explode("\n", $choices);
```

**it does populate the select field but that’s not the way how to do it right..?**

```
function yl_load_booking_time_field_choices( $field ) {

    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    $minutes = get_field('booking_settings_openings_hours_interval', 'booking_settings');

    // get the value from options page without any formatting
    if( have_rows('booking_settings_opening_hours', 'booking_settings') ) :
        while ( have_rows('booking_settings_opening_hours', 'booking_settings') ) : the_row();

            $start      = get_sub_field('booking_settings_opening_hours_start', 'booking_settings');
            $end        = get_sub_field('booking_settings_opening_hours_end', 'booking_settings');

            $startDate  = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $start);
            $endDate    = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $end);
            $interval   = new DateInterval('PT'.$minutes.'M');
            $dateRange  = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate);

            $choices = array();

            foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
                $dates = $date->format('H:i');
                $choices[] = $dates;
            }

            // explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
            $choices = explode("\n", $choices);

            // remove any unwanted white space
            $choices = array_map('trim', $choices);

            // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
            if( is_array($choices) ) {
                foreach( $choices as $choice ) {
                    $field['choices'][ $choice ] = $choice;
                }
            }

        endwhile;
    endif;

    // return the field
    return $field;

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=booking_time', 'yl_load_booking_time_field_choices');
```

Comment: `echo explode("\n", $choices);` makes little sense, you can not output an array with echo, that will only ever get you the _word_ “Array”. It looks like you mostly copy&pasted this from https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/ - but there the input value is a multi-line text string, and therefor needs exploding. […]

Comment: […] Here however your $choices _is_ an array already, you explicitly created it that way in your loop, `$choices[] = $dates;`. So there is no exploding by newline to _get_ an array necessary here in the first place, and since the $dates are just `H:i` formatted times, it does not even make sense (no newline in there at all.)